# How to accurately sum/aggregate a SQL Running Total?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below scenario (CTE SQL example) where we have product sales data at this granularity;

- date level
- source (device, country)
- fiscal period (year, week)
- product information (group)

I have a Running Total using Over Partition By, "FYTD" = Fiscal Year To Date, which seems to work as expected counting the running total by the various dimensions, but when I sum that in the final results it is inflated, as we are summing the FYTD values as of each day, rather than at the most recent level of granularity.

How can we return the accurate, true FYTD sum as of the most recent day in the results, with a solution that is scalable to a bigger results set with more fiscal years/weeks? I am testing this in Snowflake.

```
with rawdata as (
    select * from
        values
            ('2022-10-01', 2022, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-01', 2022, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Flip Flops', 1),
            ('2022-10-01', 2022, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Sunglasses', 5),
            ('2022-10-01', 2022, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-01', 2022, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2022, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2022, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-02', 2022, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 4),
            ('2022-10-03', 2022, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-03', 2022, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-03', 2022, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 5),
            ('2022-10-01', 2022, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-01', 2022, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-01', 2022, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2022, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2022, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-02', 2022, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 4),
            ('2022-10-03', 2022, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-03', 2022, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-03', 2022, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 5),
            ('2022-10-08', 2022, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 7),
            ('2022-10-08', 2022, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 8),
            ('2022-10-08', 2022, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 4),
            ('2022-10-09', 2022, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 6),
            ('2022-10-09', 2022, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-09', 2022, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 8),
            ('2022-10-10', 2022, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 12),
            ('2022-10-10', 2022, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 22),
            ('2022-10-10', 2022, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 5),
            ('2022-10-08', 2022, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 4),
            ('2022-10-08', 2022, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-08', 2022, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-09', 2022, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 3),
            ('2022-10-09', 2022, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 8),
            ('2022-10-09', 2022, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 9),
            ('2022-10-10', 2022, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 5),
            ('2022-10-10', 2022, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 4),
            ('2022-10-10', 2022, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 13),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 4),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 5),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 4),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 5),
            ('2022-10-08', 2023, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 7),
            ('2022-10-08', 2023, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 8),
            ('2022-10-08', 2023, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 4),
            ('2022-10-09', 2023, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 6),
            ('2022-10-09', 2023, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-09', 2023, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 8),
            ('2022-10-10', 2023, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 12),
            ('2022-10-10', 2023, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 22),
            ('2022-10-10', 2023, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 5),
            ('2022-10-08', 2023, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 4),
            ('2022-10-08', 2023, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-08', 2023, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-09', 2023, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 3),
            ('2022-10-10', 2023, 2, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 5),
            ('2022-10-10', 2023, 2, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 4),
            ('2022-10-10', 2023, 2, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 13)
         as a (date, fiscalyearno, fiscalweekno, devicegroup, usercountry, productgroup, bookings)
    ),
    
    resultsset as (
    select  date
            , fiscalyearno
            , fiscalweekno
            , devicegroup
            , usercountry
            , productgroup 
            , sum(bookings) as totalbookings
            , dense_rank()
                over 
                    (partition by fiscalyearno, devicegroup, usercountry, productgroup order by date desc, fiscalweekno desc) as fytddr    
            , sum(totalbookings)
                over 
                    (partition by fiscalyearno, devicegroup, usercountry, productgroup order by date, fiscalweekno asc) as fytdbookings
    from rawdata
    group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
    )

//select * from resultsset
//order by 1,2,3,4,5,6

select  fiscalyearno
        , fiscalweekno
        , sum(totalbookings) as totalbookings
        , sum(iff(fytddr = 1, fytdbookings, 0)) as fytdbookings
from resultsset
group by 1,2
order by 2
```

As you can see below, the dense_rank approach works as long as the dimensions are consistent in each time period, with values populated. Where this falls down is if we have a product in an earlier period (i.e. FW1) which is not in the latest period (i.e. FW2). Below you can see that splits the FYTD value into 6 and 161 for FW1 and FW2 respectively, whereas I am requiring the full 167 in FW2, as that is the correct FYTD Total as of FW2.

[image: tableresultsexample]

Comment: I can move the sum over partition by fiscalyearno order by fiscalweekno into the final query to get the right result for that specific use case, but as the requirements change and we may or may not need FYTD total by certain dimension, we need to ensure it's both in the resultset and final results.

Comment: Where the dense_rank approach is falling down is if there is a product in Fiscal Week 1 which did not have any sales in Fiscal Week 2. Then that has dense_rank = 1 in FW1, meaning the aggregated FYTD across the column is correct, but it doesn't show correctly when filtered to the most recent Fiscal Week (2).

Comment: If I was to add some records with null value for flip flop and sunglasses in FW2 I get the right 167 total. But not sure how to do that on 'real' tables plus it would inflate row count when there might be a better method.

Comment: Ideally I need the true FYTD value to hold true whether I use fiscalyearno, fiscalweekno or date in the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not overcounting. You're summing a running sum. If you have a running sum on 1, 2, 3, you'll get 1, 3, 6. If you have a sum of that running sum you'll get 10. I'm not sure why you'd want a running sum and then aggregate it. It wipes out the detail the running sum provides. Also, in order to get through the aggregation the SQL is feeding `totalbookings` (an alias for an aggregated sum) into the sum window function. That's interesting at best and unpredictable at worst.

You can see the sum of the running sum issue if you shortcut your CTE and look at the results of the window function:

```
with rawdata as (
    select * from
        values
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 4),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Shoes', 1),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Shoes', 2),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Shoes', 5),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-01', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-02', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 4),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Desktop', 'UK', 'Socks', 1),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Mobile', 'UK', 'Socks', 2),
            ('2022-10-03', 2023, 1, 'Tablet', 'UK', 'Socks', 5)
         as a (date, fiscalyearno, fiscalweekno, devicegroup, usercountry, productgroup, bookings)
    ),
    
    resultsset as (
    select  date
            , fiscalyearno
            , fiscalweekno
            , devicegroup
            , usercountry
            , productgroup 
    --        , sum(bookings) as totalbookings
            , sum(bookings)
                over 
                    (partition by fiscalyearno, fiscalweekno, devicegroup, usercountry, productgroup order by date asc) as fytdbookings
    from rawdata
   -- group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
    )

select * from resultsset;
```

| DATE | FISYNO | FISWEEKNO | DEVGRP | USRCNTRY | PRODGRP | FYTDBOOK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | 2023 | 1 | Desktop | UK | Shoes | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2023 | 1 | Mobile | UK | Shoes | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2023 | 1 | Tablet | UK | Shoes | 1 |
| 2022-10-02 | 2023 | 1 | Desktop | UK | Shoes | 2 |
| 2022-10-02 | 2023 | 1 | Mobile | UK | Shoes | 4 |
| 2022-10-02 | 2023 | 1 | Tablet | UK | Shoes | 5 |
| 2022-10-03 | 2023 | 1 | Desktop | UK | Shoes | 3 |
| 2022-10-03 | 2023 | 1 | Mobile | UK | Shoes | 6 |
| 2022-10-03 | 2023 | 1 | Tablet | UK | Shoes | 10 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2023 | 1 | Desktop | UK | Socks | 1 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2023 | 1 | Mobile | UK | Socks | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 | 2023 | 1 | Tablet | UK | Socks | 1 |
| 2022-10-02 | 2023 | 1 | Desktop | UK | Socks | 2 |
| 2022-10-02 | 2023 | 1 | Mobile | UK | Socks | 4 |
| 2022-10-02 | 2023 | 1 | Tablet | UK | Socks | 5 |
| 2022-10-03 | 2023 | 1 | Desktop | UK | Socks | 3 |
| 2022-10-03 | 2023 | 1 | Mobile | UK | Socks | 6 |
| 2022-10-03 | 2023 | 1 | Tablet | UK | Socks | 10 |

Notice the running sum is in some cases higher than any individual values, so that explains the higher total when summing the running sum.

As far as how to fix this, I'm not sure. It would help to have a desired output table because as previously mentioned, calculating a running sum only to aggregate it is something that loses the detail of that running sum.

Comment: Thanks Greg!  I am getting close to what I want using dense_rank, but not sure if it's the best solution.  I get what you mean, there's value in the running sum itself, but also in the absolute FYTD value.

Comment: Added to post, as couldn't drop code here.